# Staging Server VM Setup out of existing Production Server

Tags: virtual-machines

We are rolling out a big change that affects many of our apps. We see that everything works perfectly in DEV.

In order to minimize downtime, we want to stage a go-live. For that, we will setup a Staging server where we will run scripts and copy the latest code.

In order to minimize setup, we want to Virtualize our Prod server into a Staging Server.

For that we have Virtualized a copy of the Prod Server.

I seek advice on best approach to turn this VM ON without causing issues such as server name and IP conflicts.

Should we run Sysprep on the VM before starting it up? If so, how does one boot a VM with Sysprep bootstrapped to it?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't Sysprep a machine pre-boot. You can disconnect the vNIC of this machine, boot it up and then run Sysprep.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running it with the vNIC disconnected when you boot it. This would work if your app can run completely inside the VM.

If you need access to some external network resources, then configure the firewall at the hypervisor to only allow traffic to/from those specific hosts.  The more open the firewall, the greater chance there is for conflicts with your current prod system.  You should plan this very carefully using documentation of the app and its network dependencies.